# How to pass a JSON object to an action

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, jquery

I have the following jQuery code in a View in MVC3. I want to load a partial view (named `OffshoreECore`) in a div (`#Form`) depending on the JSON object passed in the success function. Here's the code:

```
var inputParamtrs = { 'HeadId': $('#ExpenseId').val(), MProjid': $('#MProjid').val() };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Expenses/Edit",
    data: inputParamtrs,
    success:  function (json) {
        ('#Form').load('@Url.Action("OffShoreECore", *What comes here ?!?*)');
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `load()` is the `data` which should be sent to the specified URL along with the request. To send your JSON string, try this:

```
success:  function (json) {
    $('#Form').load('@Url.Action("OffShoreECore")', json);
}
```

You example code is also missing a `'` delimiter from the second key in `inputParamtrs` and the `$` from the selector in `success`, but I guess they're just typos.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rory. However, i have tried it and its doesnt seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("/Expenses/Edit",
    {
        HeadId: $('#ExpenseId').val(), 
        MProjid: $('#MProjid').val() 
    },
    function (data) {
        elementForResult.innerHTML = data;
    });
```

In Controller:

```
public JsonResult Edit(int HeadId, int MProjid)
    {
        ...
        var result = SerializeControl("~/Views/Expenses/Edit.cshtml", null);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

private string SerializeControl(string controlPath, object model)
    {
        var control = new RazorView(ControllerContext, controlPath, null, false, null);
        ViewData.Model = model;
        var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter());
        control.Render(new ViewContext(ControllerContext, control, ViewData, TempData, writer), writer);
        string value = writer.InnerWriter.ToString();
        return value;
    }
```